# rails active record traversing rows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am accessing a database table with the .where() method. This should return many rows.  How can I view the first row, or the second row. I know I can use the .each method to traverse all rows but what if I just want to access a certain row. I am new to rails, so sorry for this simple question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the first row, you can just use `.first`

```
Model.where(:state => "active").first
```

`.last` works the same way:

```
Model.where(:state => "active").last
```

To get the nth row, use `[]` with a 0-based index, as with any other array

```
Model.where(:state => "active")[1] #second result
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying that already and it was returning nil. Figured out my problem was that I didnt save the objects back into the database.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have your set of results you can just reference individual rows with the `[]` method.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D

```
results = YourClass.where(:foo => 'bar').all
results[0] # the first result
results[1] # the 2nd

# and so on until
results[results.length - 1] # the last item in the array
results[results.length]     # out of bounds, and returns nil

# you can also use negative numbers to count backwards
results[-1] # the last element
results[-2] # the 2nd from last
```

Comment: once one has all the results, any idea how can one print out all the values of a particular column to a single string?